# Open source TabBarController with VC in Xib to storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xib

I'm using an open source project from GitHub called [ESTabBarController](https://github.com/ezescaruli/ESTabBarController). I downloaded the example project but the problem was that the developer was using Xib files for each view controller but for the app I'm developing I was using Main.storyboard I tried searching for other questions here and posted in the issues in the GitHub project and tried my best in Xcode to use storyboard instead of Xib but honestly nothing worked. Can anybody help me please?

This is probably my first question here and I'm a new iOS developer so I don't know if I'm dumb enough to ask this but I would really appreciate help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can simply copy paste the elements in xib to your view controller in storyboard. Unless there are no constraints

Comment: @Mr.T Well, I did, but it didn't work. I put a view controller in storyboard with a label and connecting it to .m and .h files but it didn't work, the label never showed up, the only way it showed up when I put it in a Xib file.

Comment: what is the file owner for xib?

Comment: @Mr.T Sorry for the late reply. The file owner of every Xib file in the example app is it's own .h file for example the file owner of MapViewController.xib is MapViewController which redirects you when you click the little arrow button to MapViewController.h